# How to print extended value ascii for a string in java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have requirement where i have to print ascii value for a string, when i try printing the values its printing unexpected value,my program looks like below

```
  int s=1161;

  String hex=Integer.toHexString(1161);
   hex="0"+hex;

  char firstByte = (char) (Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(0,2),16));
  char secondByte = (char) (Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2,4),16));
```

and the output if the program is 
first byte-- some rectangle shape
second byte--?

where i'm expecting the ascii code are 
first byte-- EOT
second byte--‰

can some one help me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Please try to explain yourself better. It is not clear what would you like to print. Could you probably give and example: what would you like to print for number `1161`?

Comment: Hi AlexR,actually the number 1161 is the length of a string which is returned from some other fucntion. then i'm converting into hexdecimal and trying to convert the hex string itno ascii code. the output i'm expecting for the first substring :EoT and for the second substring : ‰ . apologies if i put u in confusion .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You intend to do tbe following in a somewhat convoluted way:

```
String hex = String.format("%04x", s); // delivering 0489
```

The first byte is 0x04 = 4, an ASCII control char, Ctrl-D, or EOT.

The second byte is 89, is actually out of the 7bit ASCII range. Depending on the encoding that might be the promil sign, but in Unicode would be the Unicode control character for a tab with justification.

Comment: that is true Joop, 89 is out of 7 bit and it is part of extended ascii right. is there any way to print 128 to 255 range

Comment: @yarra, 0x89 does not belong to 7bit java US-ASCII, but you probably mean, but code pages cover the full 8 bits, with different characters per code page. And you mean the extended Windows Latin-1 code page, Windows-1252 (alias Cp1252).

Answer (score 0):

You should try following code...

```
    int s = 1161;

    String hex = Integer.toHexString(s);
    // hex="0"+hex;

    char firstByte = (char) (Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16));
    char secondByte = (char) (Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2, 3), 16));

    System.out.println("First = " + firstByte + ", Second = " + secondByte + ", Hex " + hex);
```

**output**

```
First = H, Second =     , Hex 489
```

Comment: he wants (char)0x04 and (char)0x89, not (char)0x48 and (char)0x9.

Comment: no, it doesn't. "H" is 0x48. Exactly what he did not want to print out!

Comment: Because ascii of 48 is H that is currect value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As example said I'm expecting the the ascci code for (char)0x04 and (char)0x89  which would be EOT and ‰ .

Answer (score 0):

Test your functions with more reliable input. Control characters like EOT may be represented by squares or any other kind of placeholder. Anything above 127 is not uniquely defined in ascii, so it might just show up as "?". Seems to me your function works correctly.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii for all well defined ascii symbols.